# Modeling a permission tree in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, permissions, typing

I am trying to model a permission tree, which looks like this (JSON):

```
{
  DOMAIN_1: {CREATE: true, EDIT: true, DELETE: true, READ: true},
  DOMAIN_2: {CREATE: true, EDIT: true, DELETE: true, READ: true}
  DOMAIN_3: {CREATE: true, EDIT: true, DELETE: true, READ: true}
  ...
}
```

(of course DOMAIN_1, and the others are representing actual business domains, like CUSTOMERS etc.)

I could just type this object like so: `const permissionTree: {[domain: string]: {[type: string]: boolean};`. However, I tried to do something more strict and came up with the following code:

```
enum PermissionArea {
    DOMAIN_1 = 'DOMAIN_1',
    DOMAIN_2 = 'DOMAIN_2',
    ...
}

enum PermissionType {
    CREATE = 'CREATE',
    READ = 'READ',
    EDIT = 'EDIT',
    DELETE = 'DELETE'
}

type PermissionsTree = {
    [key in PermissionArea]: { [type in PermissionType]: boolean };
};

export class Permission {
    public static create(area: PermissionArea, type: PermissionType): string {
        return `${area}.${type}`;
    }
}

const isPermission = (x: any): x is Permission => {
    if (typeof x !== 'string') {
        return false;
    }

    const keys = x.split('.');

    if (keys.length !== 2) {
        return false;
    }

    return keys[0] in PermissionArea && keys[1] in PermissionType;
};
```

Whereas this seems to be a better approach than the first one, it is not ideal. First of all, my `Permission` is actually a `string`, and whenever I want to use methods, like `split`, I need to specify the type as string or cast it. This defies the purpose of typing it, like in the example below (error will be in runtime, not in compilation time):

```
const isAuthorized = (
    permission: string,
    userPermissions: PermissionsTree
): boolean | undefined => {
    if (!isPermission(permission)) {
        throw new Error(`${permission} is not an allowed permission!`);
    } else {
        return userPermissions[getPermissionArea(permission)][getPermissionType(permission)];
    }
};
```

Also, creating a permission is a bit verbose, this is a usage example:

```
const AUTH_ROUTES: AuthenticatedRoute[] = [
    ...
    {
        path: '/users',
        component: <Users/>,
        permissions: [Permission.create(PermissionArea.USER, PermissionType.READ)]
    },
    ...
```

Do you have any suggestions how to improve those typings leaving the permissions tree in JSON unchanged?